# Call animations by condition?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I apologize in advance for bad English. Recently, I ran into a problem that I can’t solve. The documentation for jQuery on did not give me the necessary information or I'm just stupid.

I have several animations that should work according to the following principle:
If the mouse cursor is on the upper half of the screen, then the button appears; if on the bottom, it disappears.
My logic turned out to be not working and therefore the condition only works once upon entering / reloading the page. That is, the animation is not performed dynamically
the code:

```
$.fn.offsetAnimate=()=>{
$('#body').mousemove(e=>{
    let offset=$('#body').offset();
    let mouseY=(e.pageY-offset.top);
        mouseY<=$('#body').height()/2?$.fn.fadeInTest():$.fn.fadeOutTest()

})
```

}

that's my logic.
that's my custom animation(2):

```
`$.fn.fadeOutTest=()=>{
$('.button').animate({
    'width':'100px'
},1000,()=>{

})
console.log('check')
```

}`

```
$.fn.fadeInTest=(elem)=>{


    $('.button').animate({
        'padding':'0',
        'width':'0%',

        'transition':"all .3s linear"

    },1600)
console.log('test')
```

}

I want to note that the values in the console are always called when the mouse is moved, but the styles themselves change only once.
I would be grateful for any help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this to prevent animation build up. I also fixed some syntax error in your code

```js
$.fn.offsetAnimate=()=>{
  $('#body').mousemove(e=>{
      let offset=$('#body').offset();
      let mouseY=(e.pageY-offset.top);
      mouseY<=$('#body').height()/2?$.fn.fadeInTest():$.fn.fadeOutTest()
  })
}

$.fn.fadeOutTest=()=>{
  if (!$('.button').hasClass('fade-out')){
    $('.button').removeClass('fade-in').addClass('fade-out');
    $('.button').animate({
        'width':'100px'
    },1000)
  }

}

$.fn.fadeInTest=()=>{
  if (!$('.button').hasClass('fade-in')){
    $('.button').removeClass('fade-out').addClass('fade-in');
      $('.button').animate({
        'padding':'0',
        'width':'0%',

        'transition':"all .3s linear"

    },1600)
  }

 }
 
 $.fn.offsetAnimate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body id="body" style="height: 100vh">
<button class="button" styld="width: 0px">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, you're incredible. It worked. I am incredibly grateful to you :)